# Simple android app crashed

Tags: android

So I'm kind of new in this Android development but I eager to learn so as long as I learn more stuff I would thank you more!
I wrote a code just for fun, there is a bottom with some context but it's doesn't matter, it's all works until I click the bottom, the bottom needs to go to a function that needs to low\high the brightness in the current android platform but from some reason when I'm clicking the bottom the app crashed..
here is the function in the main activity(java file):
EDIT: the function taken from some question in this site

```
public void ChangeBrightness(View v)
    {
        Settings.System.putInt(this.getContentResolver(),
                Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS, 20);

        WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = getWindow().getAttributes();
        lp.screenBrightness =0.2f;;
        getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        finish();
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Comment: Add error stack trace if you want some help !

Comment: crash -> read the stacktrace